# How do I get the TOTAL price from the updated state? (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, state, store, price

***I need to dynamically update the total when an item is added***

selectedProducts is the array being updated onClick with the selected item, the item includes the price (in the object: 'price'), i need to get the price of the total items, and update totalPrice accordingly.

*** I am trying to keep everything in one function if possible ***

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    products: products,
    selectedProducts: [],
    totalPrice: 0,
  };

  handleQuantityChange = id => {
    const carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts;
    const price = products.map(id => id.price).find((id)=> {
      return id
    } )
    const priceAddition = price
    const oldPrice = this.state.totalPrice;
    const newPrice = oldPrice + priceAddition;
    this.setState({
      selectedProducts: [...carsSelected, id],
                        totalPrice:newPrice,
    });

  };
```

Comment: What is the question here? You seem to have a solution, what's not working?

Comment: i keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your method with a functional form of `setState`:

```
 handleQuantityChange = id => {
   const product = products.find(product => product.id === id)

   this.setState(state => ({
     selectedProducts: [...state.selectedProducts, id],
     totalPrice: state.totalPrice + product.price,
   }));
 };
```

Comment: i tried it and it return: TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined,          const carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts;
    const product = products.find(product => product.id === id)

    const priceAddition = product.price
    const oldTotal = this.state.totalPrice
    const newPrice = priceAddition + oldTotal
    this.setState({
      selectedProducts: [...carsSelected, id],
      totalPrice: newPrice
    });

Answer (score 0):

Because find method does return matched record as array object. 
so you have replace above your find method line with these lines

```
const product = products.find(product => product.id === id)
const {price=0}=product[0] && product[0] || {};
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but im having trouble implementing your answer can you show me exactly what you mean? (im new to react)

Answer (score 0):

ive solved the issue, all i had to do was:

```
 handleQuantityChange = id => {
    const carsSelected = this.state.selectedProducts
    const oldTotal = this.state.totalPrice
    const newPrice = id.price + oldTotal
    this.setState({
      selectedProducts: [...carsSelected, id],
      totalPrice: newPrice
    });
  };
```

thanks for everyone help